# Oracle 10g on Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac-osx, installation, oracle, oracle10g

I have found a couple of pages on how to get this configured on Leopard ([link](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/04/12/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-intel/) and [link](http://www.pythian.com/news/1937/quick-install-guide-for-oracle-10g-release-2-on-mac-os-x-leopard-intel)), and then apparently an upgrade to Snow Leopard does not seem to complicate matters much. However, I'm already on Snow Leopard, and there are numerous problems with:

- The lack of JVM 1.4.2 on Snow Leopard (which I have installed on Snow Leopard, so I'm over this hurdle)
- The change in the base version of gcc on Snow Leopard (which causes all sorts of linking issues apparently.

The solution seems to be to install Leopard on an external drive, boot from that drive,  install XCode under Leopard, then install Oracle to the external drive, with a symbolic link that actually directs the install to your Snow Leopard drive.

While this makes sense when I read it, this last step has me a bit thrown. Can anyone who has successfully done this explain to me how to proceed? (i.e. which symbolic links should be made, and how to work through the install?) Seems to be there's a LOT about the install that can't be processed through a symbolic link (user/group creation, Oracle auto-startup options, etc.)

If anyone out there has successfully done this (especially if they kept notes!) I could sure use some help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as though one of the above links has recently updated his site with directions on exactly how to do what I was asking.

[Oracle 10g on Snow Leopard](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/)

He includes a download to the pre-compiled Leopard binary that does not compile under Snow Leopard (because of an updated gcc and linking issues). I know that not everyone wants to run something pre-compiled, but I did, and it works like a charm.

Strangely enough, I have installed both Java 1.4.2 and 1.5.0 from Leopard, with all the appropriate symbolic links (and they work just fine) and I still had to update Oracle to use 1.5.0 as he indicates in his directions. 1.4.2 would not do it.

Hope this helps someone.